# RxDB/Electron storing data in sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, ionic-framework, electron, rxdb

I want to build a hybrid using Ionic/Electron to run it on Desktop,Browser and Android, after doing some research i found about RxDB which by it's definition seems to fit this kind of DB usage (https://rxdb.info/) 
I want to be able to store data locally in an SQLite-like storage capacity without being limited by the web browser's storage capacity and use the same api (rxdb ?) to manipulate data on Desktop (Electron), Mobile and web browser (Ionic).
Is this possible using RxDB ? if it's not i would like to know if there are tools out there capable of allowing such functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is surely possible with RxDB, you can use IDB which stands for indexed data storage, which in terms of browser means that your data will not be limited by the browser capacity, since it is stored offline in your computer,

> It is limited only to your available disk space  Not to the browser capacity 
>   That is what idb adapter helps in browsers